# What is wrong with this simple code which contains float variables and scanf_s?

Tags: c

I'm beginner in C programming.
When I debugged my code below, the value of 'amount' variable is something strange, which I didn't select from 'scanf_s'.
What is wrong with this code?

I've tried to find solution for this error, by erasing all of statements except

```
float amount, WTA;

printf("Enter an amount: ");
scanf_s("&.2f", &amount);
```

and adding

```
printf("With tax added: $%.2f", amount);
```

and I conclude that this part :

```
float amount, WTA;

printf("Enter an amount: ");
scanf_s("&.2f", &amount);
```

is wrong.
Why? What's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    float amount, WTA;

    printf("Enter an amount: ");
    scanf_s("&.2f", &amount);

    WTA = 1.05f*amount;
    printf("With tax added: $%.2f", WTA);

    return 0;
}
```

I want to see result like this.

```
Enter an amount: 50.00
With tax added: 52.50
```

Comment: You have to use `%` instead of `&` in the format string.

Comment: scanf uses `%`, not `&`.  Change `to scanf_s("%.2f", &amount);`

Comment: Also, don't use `scanf_s`.  In fact, don't use `scanf` at all.

Comment: Thanks to everyone leaving a comment. I understand what's wrong.

Comment: But, why I should refrain from using scanf or scanf_s? Could you explain why?

Comment: @김재우 You shouldn't use `scanf_s`, or any of the other `_s` functions, because they are only available on Windows and don't actually solve the problems they were supposed to solve.  You shouldn't use `scanf` for several reasons, but the important one right now is that `scanf("%.2f")` will only consume a number from the input. What you want is to consume _whatever the user typed_, even if it's not a number, and then try to parse it as a number, and report an error if it isn't.  The best way to do that is with `fgets` and `strtod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the & in the scanf_s statement with an % . scanf reads a float "%.2f" for conversion.

```
   scanf_s("%.2f",&amount);
```

Edit: I am also new to programming, studying C. I'm glad to see I understood the problem.

Comment: Thank you for answering my problem !